# ASP.NET MVC calling a differen't controller's action from JavaScript

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I am at an ASP.NET MVC page located at the following address:

http://somedomain/someapp/Foo/Bar?param=val

I have a **Foo** controller and also a **Bar** controller. I need to call the **Bar** controller's *DoSomething* action and pass it along the parameters I already have in the current URL's query string:

http://somedomain/someapp/Bar/DoSomething?param=val

I can't just set the AJAX call's URL to "/Bar/DoSomething" because that takes me to the following address:

http://somedomain/Bar/DoSomething?param=val

I can't specify the entire URL, as this will vary depending on the deployment.

I'm assuming there's some way of doing this using MapRoutes that will achieve what I want and pass along the data as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have the url with parameters, you can do something like:

```
ResolveUrl("~/Bar/DoSomething?param=val");
```

Which would convert the given virtual url to an absolute url

Answer (score 1):

There is at least 3 possibilities :

1 - you can have a "global" variable in javascript where you set the value of the web application base and replace the "http://somedomain.com/someapp/" with the variable :

```
var liveString = "http://" + window.location.host;
if (liveString.indexOf('somedomain.com') > 0) {
    liveString = liveString + '/someapp';
} else if (liveString .indexOf('localhost') > 0) {
    liveString = liveString + '/localApp';
}
```

You can also have a link that yo get the url in jQuery :

```
<a id="link-id" href="<%Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName", new { param = val })%>" style="display:none;"></a>

var myUrlCall = $('#link-id').href;
```

You can also create an application at the root in IIS 7 using an other port or adding it in your host file so your url could look like : htttp://someapp.local, we use this last option since it's the one that better represent the live application.

Let me know if you need more help!

Answer (score 0):

Check out Ajax.ActionLink
You can specify the name of the controller there, and the code to be invoked on success, failure etc.

ASP.NET MVC 2